# Access SQL database from an iPhone app Via RESTful WCF service

Tags: ios, iphone, sql, wcf, web-services

I have created a small project that can read and insert data from iPhone to sql server via RESTful WCF service.

I have read the data successfully with the following approach:

1- I have created a wcf web service that read data from Sql serverwith table Employees(firstname,lastname,salary):

```
"41.142.251.142/JsonWcfService/GetEmployees.svc/json/employees"
```

2- I have created a new project in xcode 5.0.2, and I added a textfield (viewData.text) to display data retrieved by the web service.
3- I added the following instruction in my viewController.m :

```
    "#define WcfSeviceURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"41.142.251.142/JsonWcfService/GetEmployees.svc/json/employees"]"
```

3- In (void)viewDidLoad method, I implemented the below code:

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:WcfSeviceURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

    if(!error)
    {
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                              JSONObjectWithData:data 
                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                              error:&error];  

        NSMutableArray *array= [json objectForKey:@"GetAllEmployeesMethodResult"];

        for(int i=0; i< array.count; i++)
        {
            NSDictionary *empInfo= [array objectAtIndex:i];

            NSString *first = [empInfo objectForKey:@"firstname"];
            NSString *last = [empInfo objectForKey:@"lastname"];
            NSString *salary  = [empInfo objectForKey:@"salary"];

            //Take out whitespaces from String
            NSString *firstname = [first
                                   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
            NSString *lastname = [last
                                   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

            viewData.text= [viewData.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ makes $%@.00 per year.\n",firstname,lastname,salary]];
        }

    }
}
```

Check the following link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/405189/How-to-access-SQL-database-from-an-iPhone-app-Via.

As I mentioned, I can read the data from my iPhone without any problem.

So the second step is how to write and insert data from the iPhone to sql server.
for this, I created first the method that insert data in my webservice:

**In WCF interface:**

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "json/InsertEmployee/{id1}/{id2}/{id3}")]
    bool InsertEmployeeMethod(string id1,string id2, string id3);
```

**In Implementation:**

```
      public bool InsertEmployeeMethod(string id1,string id2, string id3)
   {

       int success = 0;

       using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=(local);database=EmpDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
       {
           conn.Open();

           decimal value= Decimal.Parse(id3);
           string cmdStr = string.Format("INSERT INTO EmpInfo VALUES('{0}','{1}',{2})",id1,id2,value);
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn);
           success = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

           conn.Close();
       }

       return (success != 0 ? true : false);
   }
```

So to test this web servcie method use:

```
"41.142.251.142/JsonWcfService/GetEmployees.svc/json/InsertEmployee/myName/MylastName/6565"
```

Then to consume this method from iPhone I used the following approach:
 I decalared the Define Instruction:

```
"#define BaseWcfUrl [NSURL URLWithString: 
@"41.142.251.142/JsonWcfService/GetEmployees.svc/json/InsertEmployee/{id1}/{id2}/{id3}"]"
```

Then I implemented the Insert Employee Method related to click button.

```
      -(void) insertEmployeeMethod

{

if(firstname.text.length && lastname.text.length && salary.text.length)

{

    NSString *str = [BaseWcfUrl stringByAppendingFormat:@"InsertEmployee/%@/%@/%@",firstname.text,lastname.text,salary.text];

    NSURL *WcfServiceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    [request setURL:WcfServiceURL];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // connect to the web

    NSData *respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    // NSString *respStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:respData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSError *error;

    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 

                          JSONObjectWithData:respData 

                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 

                          error:&error];  



    NSNumber *isSuccessNumber = (NSNumber*)[json objectForKey:@"InsertEmployeeMethodResult"];
```

//create some label field to display status

```
        status.text = (isSuccessNumber && [isSuccessNumber boolValue] == YES) ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Inserted %@, %@",firstname.text,lastname.text]:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed to insert %@, %@",firstname.text,lastname.text];
    }

}
```

But the issue here, is in the following instruction:

```
 NSString *str = [BaseWcfUrl stringByAppendingFormat:@"InsertEmployee/%@/%@/%@",firstname.text,lastname.text,salary.text];
```

Always the system returns a message **'Data parameter nil'** with this line, knowing that the firstname.text, and lastname.text, salary are all filled and I can see their values with `NSLog(@"First Name :%@",firstname.text)...`

Can you please help on this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think NSURLs stringByAppendingFormat will do what you want.

Try something like this:

```
#define kBase_URL                @"41.142.251.142/JsonWcfService/GetEmployees.svc/json/%@"

#define kAuthAPI_InsertEmployee_URL   [NSString stringWithFormat:kBase_URL, @"InsertEmployee/%@/%@/%@"]

//Setup session
NSError *error;
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:kAuthAPI_InsertEmployee_URL,firstname.text,lastname.text,salary.text]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:requestURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:profileData options:0 error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

etc. etc.
```